# Ionic v1 close all opened modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my problem, I have a function inside `$rootScope` that is used inside many different ionic modals. That function switches states, and when it switches I want to close the currently opened modal automatically.

The thing is that I cannot write (for example) `$scope.someModal.close();` for each of the modals, as they all have different names and are in different scopes.

Is there any kind of a function that I can do something like `something.closeAllModals()` or `something.closeCurrentModal()`?

Comment: Use a service to store every modal instance... then make a function that call every modal close method

Comment: another approach is use $scope.$emit("closeAll") in rootscope and $scope.$on("closeAll") on every model. I haven't tried this out, so just a suggestion.

Comment: Can't you give a reference to currentModal when you are using the function from $rootScope. Maybe some minimal code from your application would help to understand your problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the modal to the $rootScope function:

```
 $rootScope.functionName($scope.someModal);
```

And then close it from the function

```
$rootScope.functionName = function(modal) {
  modal.close();
}
```

Comment: Not an answer I was looking for, since the function that I call from modal is in $rootScope, and modals can be in different controllers.

Comment: Then you can pass the modal to the $rootScope function and close it from there, edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

call this function in a file.

```
function closeAllwindows(isTrue) {
        if (!isTrue)
            $uibModalStack.dismissAll(); if you are using uib modal          
        $rootScope.$emit("CloseWindows", isTrue);
}
```

you use this `$rootScope.$on` into any .js file it will be `$rootScope.$emit` it from any where

```
  var closeWindows = $rootScope.$on("CloseWindows", function (name, isTrue) {
        if (isTrue) {
            closeationsheets(); // you can close the action sheet
            if (alertPopup)
                alertPopup.close(); // you can close the alert
        }
        else {           
            closeionicwindows();
            closeationsheets();
            if (alertPopup)
                alertPopup.close();
        }
    });
```